# How to reach doctrine repository in private (non-route) function in symfony5?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, entity, symfony5

When I need to access an entity repository in a public function I usually inject it with the args for that function, such as

```
public function showAction(DebitPeriod $debitPeriod, ExtraOpeningRepository $extraOpeningRepository)
```

However, when I have a private function (which is only serving as a sub-function to one of the controller routes) how can I reach the entity repository from there?

I want to be able to use it like this

```
use App\Repositories\ExtraOpeningRepository;

private function assembleEntries($units,$day = null) {
    $eor = new ExtraOpeningRepository;
}
```

or like this

```
private function assembleEntries($units,$day = null, ExtraOpeningRepository $extraOpeningRepository) {
```

The error I get is this:

> Too few arguments to function
> App\Repository\ExtraOpeningRepository::__construct(), 0 passed

I don't want to have to chain it onward all the way from the route controller like this:

```
public function showAction(DebitPeriod $debitPeriod, ExtraOpeningRepository $extraOpeningRepository) {
    $units = 1;
    $dataset = $this->assembleEntries($units,null,$extraOpeningRepository);
}

private function assembleEntries($units,$day = null, ExtraOpeningRepository $extraOpeningRepository) {
    //do stuff
}
```

IS there a way to achieve it cleaner, without the mess of the above example?

Comment: I might be missing something obvious but just inject the repository into the controller's constructor, save it in a property and then use it with `$this->extraOpeningRepository` wherever it is needed.

Comment: Oh... just lite I already do with the parameterBag and my custom service helper  I feel stupid now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per Cerad's comment, this is the successful result =)

```
use App\Repository\ExtraOpeningRepository;

class EntryController extends AbstractController
{
    private $extraOpeningRepository;

    public function __construct(ExtraOpeningRepository $extraOpeningRepository)
    {
        $this->extraOpeningRepository = $extraOpeningRepository;
    }


    private function assembleEntries($units,$day = null)
    {
        $extraOpenings = $this->extraOpeningRepository->findForDay($output[$i]['dateToFetch']);
```

Comment: Somewhat off-topic perhaps but your assembleEntries is probably not the sort of functionality that a controller should have.  Controllers in general should be as slim as possible.  Consider moving the method into it's own service.